# My late 2015 macbook pro 13" keeps freezing when installing fresh

Tags: macbook-pro, performance

I've been having issues with my late 2015 13" macbook pro for a few months now, it kept freezing (the screen would stay on but nothing would respond, not even the force track touchpad) after 5-10 minutes of working with light usage (chrome and sublime text editor). I tought this was a software issue so I pressed Command + R to start the laptop in recovery mode, deleted the start-up partition in the disk utility software and tried reinstalling macOS.

While downloading nothing went wrong however, after the macbook reboots and actually starts installing it freezes after about 1-2 minutes. Does anyone have suggestions on what I can do? I'm trying a completly fresh install.

While the laptop is in recovery mode, there are no problems and it never crashes or freezes up.